# Covert a text box value to comma seperated

Tags: javascript, html

I have two textbox in a page. The values I enter in first textbox(SRC) should be converted to comma seperated values to the second textbox(DES). Below is the code and I am able to get the first textbox value to second, but not with comma seperated. Can anyone help me on this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function convert() {
var data = document.getElementById("getcode").value;    
var lines = data.split('\n');    
var finished = [];    
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {        
var find = '(\t(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$))';        
var regex = new RegExp (find, 'g');        
var converted = lines[i].replace(regex, ',');        
finished.push(converted);    
}    
document.getElementById("displaycode").value = finished.join('\n');
}</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
Enter Code:
</br>
<textarea id="getcode"> </textarea>
</br>
<input type="button" value='Convert' onclick="convert()"/>
</br>
<textarea id="displaycode"> </textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post some examples of input into the first textbox and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The values I enter in first textbox(SRC) should be converted to comma
>   seperated values

And which values are supposed to determine this separation? I assume you want white space, just change it if that's not what you intended. Here's a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AtZ6w/2/).

And your function:

```
function convert() {
    var data = document.getElementById("SRC").value;
    var lines = data.split(' ');
    document.getElementById("DES").value = lines.join(',');
}
```

Comment: Yes, for white space its perfect. I need like, I enter a value and hit enter. So similarly I enter datas and hit enter and I need comma seperated values for those things. Like new line needs to be seperated with commas. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the magic:

```
function convert() {
    var src = document.getElementById("SRC").value,
        arr = src.split(' ');

    document.getElementById("DES").value = arr.join(',');
}
```

hope that helps.